# Smoke/Fire cards or simulations

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation, fire

HI I'm trying to create a really high quality cinematic in blender, In my animation there will be a bunch of boats on fire or smoking, (mostly) in the distance, How should I achieve a high quality effect of them on fire or smoking? [image]I've tried simulations and I'm worried that if i keep using that after 5-6 boats it might be too costly, However I have yet to see a good example of smoke cards being used in a way that actually looks good.

Any help is greatly appreciated.